# Gradle is publishing source and Javadoc JARs, but not source JAR

Tags: java, gradle, maven-central

I'm new to Gradle and attempting to publish a simple project to Maven Central. My `build.gradle` script is [nearly identical to the example](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:complete_example) in their documentation but my primary/compiled JAR is not being uploaded. Source JAR, Javadoc JAR, etc. are uploading fine but not the compiled one.

When publishing local via `publishToMavenLocal` everything works as expected. I'll note that I'm using version `6.0.1` and using `publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository` to publish to Central.

What am I missing? How can I get my compiled JARs to Central?

Update: I just realized that the POM isn't being uploaded either.

Here is the complete `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:1.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

group   = 'com.acme'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

ext.isReleaseVersion = !version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'thttpd'
            from components.java

            pom {
                name = 'thttpd'

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'The MIT License (MIT)'
                        url = 'https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
                    }
                }

                scm {
                    connection = 'scm:git:https://acme.com'
                    developerConnection = 'scm:git:https://acme.com'
                    url = 'https://acme.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        // Maven Central
        maven {
            def releasesRepoUrl  = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/'
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
            url = isReleaseVersion ? releasesRepoUrl : snapshotsRepoUrl
            credentials {
                username = nexusUsername
                password = nexusPassword
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    required { isReleaseVersion && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("publish") }
    if( required ) {
        sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up downgrading to Gradle 5.6.3 (and modifying the build script accordingly) and everything started working. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Gradle 6.6.1, removing `withSourcesJar()` doesn't help.

Comment: Nevermind, in my case the files were correctly uploaded, but not all of them appear in the web UI of my repository for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that Alexis mentions above, on the GitHub Packages web UI the sources and java-doc where not showing up. But on s01.oss.sonatype.org I was able to see them. Using Gradle 6.7